# Devise does not show correct error via login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using `devise` and `devise-token-auth` for auth in the backend and 'redux-auth` on the client side.

I'm trying to get devise to send a proper error message to show to a client in case the account is temporarily locked

this is my `user.rb` file

```
  #  devise method to check if user is banned
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && !self.banned?
  end

  # message to send in case of ban. doesnt work yet
  def inactive_message
    self.banned? ? :locked : super
  end

  def banned?
    return self.role == 'banned'
  end
```

my `devise.en.yml` file

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
    failure:
      locked: "Your account is locked."
  errors:
    messages:
      locked: "Your account has been banned"
```

I seem to be getting a standard error response from devise when trying to login either with redux-auth or CURL (i cant seem to find the given message anywhere in `devise.en.yml` file)

```
curl http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in -d "email=foo@foo.com&password=123"
```

the response

```
{"success":false,"errors":["A confirmation email was sent to your account at 'foo@foo.com'."]}
```

Where can i customize the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is in the devise_token_auth yaml file: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/123cfb730ebaf4e2acc124edd39e68816cb0b8cf/config/locales/en.yml

so you need to override it by adding the following to one of your local yaml files:

```
en:
  devise_token_auth:
    sessions:
      not_confirmed: "Custom message"
```